# Image size in ion-header-bar higher than bar itself

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have this html:

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center">
<div class="back_btn_container">
&nbsp;
</div>
<div class="logo_container">
<div style="text-align: right">
&nbsp;<img ng-src="img/newlogo2.png" />
</div>
</div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

And this css:

```
.back_btn_container{
width:20%;
padding-top: 10px;
}
.logo_container{
width:80%;
}
```

newlogo2.png is 200X45px.

When looking at the app in chrome dev tools and Iphone 5, the logo image is goes outside the boundaries of the bar. Which means: not all the logo is visible.
I don't really understand why. Shouldn't ionic.css take care of making the image not to go outside the boundaries?
This is what I hoped. Or maybe there is something else I missing here?

----EDIT-----

Please have a look at the attached image.[image: viewing app in chrome developer tools]

---EDIT 2---

Here is all the html (only the header part):

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="header_bar_logged_in bar bar-header">
    <div class="back_btn_container">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="logo_container">
        <div style="text-align: right">
            &nbsp;<img ng-src="img/newlogo2.png" src="img/newlogo2.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

And here the css relevant for the html elements:

```
.header_bar_logged_in {
background-color: blue !important;
}
.bar {
background-image: none !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
}
.bar-header {
top: 0;
border-top-width: 0;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
@media not all, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, (min-resolution: 144dpi), (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)
.bar {
border: none;
background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #ddd, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%);
background-position: bottom;
background-size: 100% 1px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.bar {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-box;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 9;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 5px;
width: 100%;
height: 44px;
border-width: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
background-color: white;
background-size: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.back_btn_container {
width: 20%;
padding-top: 10px;
}
.logo_container {
width: 80%;
}
@media (max-width: 991px)
.logo_container img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
img {
-webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

Comment: Going outside how? Please post a working code snippet that reproduce the issue

Comment: I uploaded an image now.

Comment: The image helped, but we need to see the rendered html/css, so if you can post that we can assist you

Comment: Edited again. Hope that code is enough.

Comment: Your CSS is filled with errors, so that alone can be the issue. You can't use commas like you did in your media queries as well as each media query need its own brackets `@media all (..){ rule { ... } }`, which your code doesn't have. Please update that first and repost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention at yours `bar` CSS style, the class of your `ion-header-bar`. Its height equals `44px` (and your image has got `45px`), it also has got padding defined (which is equal to `5px`).

Try to remove height property, div should automatically fit to its content.

Comment: This is likely the reason, though I recommend in the future not to post an answer when the code available is full of error. This alone can get your answer downvoted. I'm sure we all want proper written code here at SO and by posting an answer before it is, the poster might just abandon it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Give `100% width` on media queries like

```css
@media(max-width:991px){
.back_btn_container img {
  width:100%;
}
}
```

Comment: Not really working. The result is in the attached image.